# Possible to write ExpressJS/Node applications with CoffeeScript without compiling? Like connect-assets for Server

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I could use [`connect-assets`](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) to write CoffeeScript and Stylus (CSS) files without compiling and it will do the rest. Is it possible for the server side too? I could write my start my "CoffeeScript" server like:

```
coffee server.coffee
```

But I don't think it knows how to interprete CoffeeScript files directly. Is it possible to use purely CoffeeScript? Else, how what is your workflow and folder structure like? I dont want to have `coffee`s and `js`s all mixed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your application to `application.coffee`, then write this to your `app.js`:

```
require('coffee-script');
module.exports = require('./application.coffee');
```

Then `node app.js` will run your server. Off course you have to install coffee-script.

Answer (score 2):

You can just start your server the way you described it. No need to compile it.

```
coffee app.coffee
```